# Can I add a "Open in homekit app" button to my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm adding a functionality in my iOS app (Swift) that should open HomeKit with a prefilled pin for a new accessory.

Is there a way to deeplink to the Home app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code below should open HomeKit

```
let url = URL(string: "com.apple.home://launch")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: Thanks, can I add an accessory pin ? to prefill the pin field, for the user ?

Comment: I did not see anything within Apple's documentation that shows how to do this.  I'm not saying you can't, just that I was not able to find anything regarding that.